# Grails formRemote redirects rather than to just call method

Tags: ajax, grails, redirect, groovy

I'm new to Grails and got some problem with the g:formRemote command..

I want a g:textArea box send a message to my controller and save this messages.
After that the page should be **updated via** the formRemote **Ajax**, so that the messages appear on the page.

But instead of updating the page, the formRemote call assumes the given url to be a real link and wants me to redirect to this (non-existing) .jsp site.
The Method I want to start is called in my controller tho

I tried many solutions offered in similar problems, but it seems this problem is different from theirs

Heres the code:

```
<div id="history">
    <g:render template="posts" collection="${ messages }" var="message" />
</div>
<div class="postMessageForm">
    <g:formRemote name="postChatMessage" url="[controller: 'meetingRoom', 
                  action: 'postMessage']" update="history">                             
    <div class="msg_box">
        <g:textArea name="message" value="" style="width: 630px"/><br/>
    </div>
    <div style="float: right;">
        <g:submitButton name="Send" style="width: 90px; height: 40px;"/>
    </div>
    </g:formRemote>
</div>
```

and this is the Action which is called in my MeetingRoomController:

```
def postMessage() {
if (params.message != "") {
    def thisUser = lookUpUser()
    def thisRoom = thisUser.joinedRoom
    def chatPost = new ChatPost(
        message: params.message,
        author: thisUser
    )
    thisRoom.addToChatHistory(chatPost)
}
//  def messages = currentChatHistory()
//  render template: 'posts', collection: messages, var: 'message'
```

I saw this kind of approach in Jeff Browns Twitter tutorial.

Possible failures i am seeing:

- the out-commented render template command has something to do with the Ajax (When I do not comment it the only thing that happens is that the template posts will be rendered on the redirected page
- usage of both Ajax and jQuery (But i dont believe that can be the point because I just have used g: and groovy stuff and havent even imported a jQuery lib)
- this could be easier with remoteFunction (I dont really know how to get the remoteFunction work in this case tho)

I hope this information is enough to let someone see what I am missing

Answer (score 1):

When the submit button is clicked on your form, the data is sent to the method listed in the url parameter of the formRemote tag.  Then you are inside that method, you get to the commented out render tag that outputs data back to the gsp page in the div mentioned in the update tag of the formRemote tag.

formRemote relies upon a javascript library to handle the ajax stuff as mentioned in the grails documentation:

> 7.7.1 Ajax Support
>
> By default Grails ships with the jQuery library, but through the
>   Plugin system provides support for other frameworks such as Prototype,
>   Dojo:http://dojotoolkit.org/, Yahoo UI:http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/
>   and the Google Web Toolkit. This section covers Grails' support for
>   Ajax in general. To get started, add this line to the  tag of
>   your page:
>
> You can replace jQuery with any
>   other library supplied by a plugin you have installed. This works
>   because of Grails' support for adaptive tag libraries. Thanks to
>   Grails' plugin system there is support for a number of different Ajax
>   libraries including (but not limited to):
>
> jQuery Prototype Dojo YUI MooTools

So remove what is in the history div, uncomment the two lines in your postMessage method, and include one of the referenced javascript libraries.

Comment: I'm sorry, I had the feeling i forgot something ( to write additionally ) .. I had imported the lib via <g:javascript library="prototyp" /> already.. That is unfortunately not the problem. I tried to leave the render command in the html code, but the render command in my controller is executed in this new (non-existing) postMessage.gsp . So instead of getting the update="history" right, he tries to redirect to a gsp file based on my action= input.

Comment: in developer tools for your browser, do you see the prototype.js file or something similar getting pulled in?

Comment: you were right, the prototype.js was not imported by the <g:javascript library="prototype" command. i had to use the parameter src="prototype/prototype.js" instead.. Now the prototype.js is imported perfectly fine. However, the Ajax command is still not toggled. Still the same behaviour. Instead of updating the "history" div, it renders the template on a new non-existing postMessage.gsp.. I'm sorry if I am a little bit dumb in this situation. Thank you for your input anyways, really appreciate it!

Comment: your formRemote is sending the session to the postMessage method which is associated to the postMessage.gsp view.  what is the url of the .gsp you have displayed?  you can make the .gsp you have displayed postMessage.gsp or you can pull the render out of the controller and put it in the history div and remove the update from the formRemote and add a redirect in the controller passing the messages variable to whatever that .gsp you have there is in

Comment: seems like it is a bigger deal than just this problem. I tried some other approaches and also some tutorials which were considered to work well. Not one Ajax Command was executed. So I think it is not necessary to search the problem inside of what I have coded, rather to search on what is wrong with the miss/noninterpretation of Ajax. I will reinstall Grails and work around a little bit..

Comment: I really think you are almost there and that your problem has to do with my last comment.